# How can I concatenate all of these XML tags into one larger tag of the same name with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath-1.0

I am transforming this XML:

```
<root>
  <contrib contrib-type="author">
    <name>
      <last-name>Kottke</last-name>
      <first-name>Leo</first-name>
    </name>
  </contrib>

  <contrib contrib-type="author">
    <name>
      <last-name>McKee</last-name>
      <first-name>Andy</first-name>
    </name>
  </contrib>

  <contrib contrib-type="author">
    <name>
      <last-name>Hedges</last-name>
      <first-name>Michael</first-name>
    </name>
  </contrib>
</root>
```

...with this XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity rule -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

        <!-- Authors -->
        <xsl:template match="contrib[@contrib-type='author']">
            <Authors>
              <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select = "concat(name/first-name, ' ', name/last-name, ', ')" />
              </xsl:if>

              <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                <xsl:value-of select = "concat('and ', name/first-name, ' ', name/last-name, '.')" />
              </xsl:if>
            </Authors>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...and am getting this output:

```
<root>
    <Authors>Leo Kottke, </Authors>
    <Authors>Andy McKee, </Authors>
    <Authors>and Michael Hedges.</Authors>
</root>
```

---

---

***However*, I am trying to concatenate all of the  `Author`  tags into one larger  `Author`  tag, so that the output would resemble this**:

```
<root>
    <Authors>Leo Kottke, Andy McKee, and Michael Hedges.</Authors>
</root>
```

Do I need to use a  `for-each`  loop in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `xsl:for-each` needed. Just add a template for `/*` (or `/root`) and remove `Authors` from your `contrib` match:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity rule -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <Authors>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="contrib[@contrib-type='author']"/>
            </Authors>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Authors -->
    <xsl:template match="contrib[@contrib-type='author']">
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:value-of select = "concat(name/first-name, ' ', name/last-name, ', ')" />
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
            <xsl:value-of select = "concat('and ', name/first-name, ' ', name/last-name, '.')" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @DevNull for the help! However, I have many other such tags to transform besides `Authors`, and appending this code to the rest of it is conflicting and causing *only* `Authors` to output...

Comment: Ah, so I changed `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>`, and now it is working fine. I'm not exactly sure what I figured out there, but it seems as if applying the Authors transformation to all attributes was nullifying all nodes that didn't match the condition. Thanks again @DevNull!

Answer (score 2):

Something a little simpler

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:variable name="authors">
            <xsl:for-each select="contrib/name">
                <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="first-name"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="last-name"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <root>
            <authors><xsl:value-of select="substring($authors,3)"/></authors>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jim for the help! However, the number of names is of unknown size (not always just 3), and the position of the `<contrib contrib-type="author">` element will vary in relation to the root...

Comment: There's nothing in my answer that limits anything to 3 occurrences.  As to the varying depth, just change the select to `.//contrib/name`.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry I misunderstood the line `<xsl:value-of select="substring($authors,3)"/>`, and thanks again for the information... so what does this statement indicate? I did get the expected results when testing at http://xsltcake.com/, however without the final "and" and period though.

Comment: Rather than conditionally append the `", "` separator, prior code ALWAYS prepends it to each name, then at the end the first one is removed.  This substring() is extracting from the variable starting at position 3, since positions 1-2 contain ", ".